# Convergence of $f_n \to f$ and $f_n'' \to g$ in $L^1$ implies $f'' = g$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Update.** Turns out that the property I am asking is just closedness of the differential operator $f \to f''$. Still, I do not know how to prove that.

> What is a standard (using definition) way to prove that the operator $A f = f''$ in $L^1(0,1)$ with $D(A) = W^{2,1}(0,1)$ is closed?

---

Let $AC^2(0,1) \subset L^1(0,1)$ be the space of functions whose first and second derivative are absolutely continuous. Assume that the sequence $(f_n) \subset AC^2(0,1)$ is such that

- $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = f$,
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'' = g$,

in $L^1$ for some functions $f, g \in L^1(0,1)$.

> Is it true that $f \in AC^2(0,1)$ and $f'' = g$?

I've tried to write
$$
f_n(x) = f_n(0) + x f_n'(0) + \int_0^x (x-y) f_n''(y) dy,
$$
but I'm not sure if $f_n(0)$ or $f_n'(0)$ converges.

I know that the convergence implies that there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that $f_{n_k}'$ and $f_{n_k}''$ converges almost everywhere but is it useful here?

Comment: I guess your way does not apply here. As you say $f_n(0)$ might be undefined. Can you rewrite your last expression but for $f_n(0.5)$ for instance?

Comment: @noether: It's not exactly the case. Since $f$ is in $AC^2$ it is continuous and has continuous derivative.